# Spaces in filename issue

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I have a weird issue.

I have a subfolder in a website (Joomla 2.5 with .htaccess, mod_rewrite and SEF urls enabled) folder that contains a bunch of PDF files.  They are directly downoaded into that folder via FTP, so I don't have much chance to fiddle with the filenames.

They look something like this:

```
1093 - Transport services in Kenya.pdf.
```

I then make a simple a link to that file as such:

```
<a href="content/1093 - Transport services in Kenya.pdf" target="_blank">View report content</a>
```

It redirects me to the front page, not to the file.  This looks like a rewrite issue?

Here is my htaccess:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

What can I do so that those PDF files can be accessible in a new tab?

Thanks

JG

Comment: 2 things to test: remove (comment) the first security rewriteCond/rewriteRule block, in case of. And try to build a valid url-encoded url (where spaces would already be set as %20) on the html page.

Comment: Sometimes error may be simple, the relative content/ is just under the home dir, have you tried /content/my big pdf file.pdf?

Answer (score 0):

i think you must change your .htaccess and allow
the spezcific IP 127.0.0.1.

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

I think your server will answered, else change your filename with from space to "-".
Greets from Germany. :-)